# OpenCL kernel draws only on diagnoal

Tags: kernel, gpu, opencl

I'm currently working on a OpenCL kernel on OSX and I'm trying to set an input image to all 255.
I created a 1-channel image with `CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` and `CL_UNSIGNED_INT8` and my kernel and host codes are as follows:

```
const sampler_t linear_sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
__kernel void test(__write_only image2d_t dst)
{
    const int2 src_pos = int2(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    write_imagei(dst, src_pos, 255);
}

void clTest(cl_image2d dst)
{        
    cl_int retval;

    cl_kernel kTest = clCreateKernel(m_oclEnv.program, "test", &retval);
    CHECK_OCL(clSetKernelArg(kTest, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dst.mem));

    size_t grid_item_size[2] = {static_cast<size_t>(m_nFrameWidth), static_cast<size_t>(m_nFrameHeight)};
    size_t block_item_size[2] = {8, 8};
    cl_uint nDim = 2;        

    CHECK_OCL(clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(m_oclEnv.queue, kTest, nDim, NULL, grid_item_size, block_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL));

    clReleaseKernel(kTest);

}
```

As a result the output image is like:
[image]

Apparently the kernel only draws at positions where y=x, so where is the problem? Thanks.

ps: I've tried writing an image to GPU and read out immediately and it works well, so there should not be any problem with opencl context or environment.

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but you need to use `write_imageui` for images of unsigned types.

Comment: Problem solved. On the first line of my opencl kernel. changing type `int2` to `(int2)`, I have no idea why the kernel acted like that before and why opencl didn't report any syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think*, the line

```
    const int2 src_pos = int2(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
```

breaks down into the following sub-expressions:

```
(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1))
```

This is the comma operator! In other words, this evaluates to just `get_global_id(1)`. So we have:

```
const int2 src_pos = int2(get_global_id(1));
```

…which replicates `get_global_id(1)` into both components of the `int2`.

Mind you, I'm not saying this syntax & interpretation is *sensible* or that the compiler should accept it without warning. Unfortunately, OpenCL compilers are pretty bad when it comes to detecting and warning you about possible undefined behaviour or possible unintended syntax compared to modern C and C++ compilers.

Comment: I have tried Intel NEO (19.25.13237), Nvidia (CUDA 10.0.292) and Pocl (with LLVM 8.0), and all three refuse to compile that kernel. So at least in this case, the problem is not in OpenCL compilers, but more likely that OP is using an ancient compiler from some ancient OS X implementation, which is crap. Apple gave up on OpenCL a long time before the official announcement, so it shouldn't be a surprise their implementation is beta-quality.